# git logic missing

Tags: logic, branch, directory, git-commit

The thing is that on a time period of 4 weeks I've developed a project on two different locations. At this point I have two different directories on my HDD, each of them containing the .git folder with all the commits.

On `folderOne` I have something like that:
`A - B - C - D - E - F - G`
On `folderTwo` I have the following commits:
`A - B - X - Y - Z`

What I need is the following:
`A - B - X - Y - Z - C - D - E - F - G`

At this point I know that I have to move the head from forlderOne to stage B

```
git br gStage                # save the G stage into a branch  
git reset --hard HEAD~5      # move master on stage B
```

Now, my intention is to `copy/paste` the content from the `folderTwo` into the `folderOne` but I know this is not the right way.

Can you tell me how can I get the `A - B - X .. - C .. G`.

also please feel free to critique my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that A and B in both repositories are actually the same (as in the same commit id), then I'd go about another way.  I would fetch `folderOne`'s branch into `folderTwo`:

```
git fetch /path/to/folderOne master:folderOne-master
```

Then, I'd use rebase:

```
git rebase master folderOne-master
```

That should replay the commits in `folderOne` master on top of the current master, taking care to leave A and B alone, since they're in common.  After this step, `folderOne-master` should have the graph:

```
A - B - X - Y - Z - C - D - E - F - G
```

Now, make sure you're on master in `folderTwo`, and merge the `folderOne-master` branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge folderOne-master
```

The last command should do a fast-forward merge, and you should see the nice linear history you've asked for.

Just to make it clear, if what you really want is the content, and don't necessarily care about a linear history, then you can do this instead:

```
git fetch /path/to/folderOne master:folderOne-master
git merge folderOne-master
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the GIT Rebasing functions: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

You should be able to push the changes from Folder One into Folder Two. Then you should end up with one repository where the code branches after commit `B`, one with `C - D - E - F - G` and the other with `X - Y - Z`.

You can then rebase the branch starting with commit C after commit Z, resulting in a single branch which you can then work from.